# Output powershell script from a VBA application depending on values inputted

Tags: powershell

Here's what I would like to archieve:

I would like to create a basic VBA application in order for people to input values which are eventually ran in a Powershell instance.

In order to so this , I would either like the program to output the values in the form in a prefined script and then the user manualy enters this in powershell or I would like the user to input their office 365 credentials prior to filling in the form and for the application to run the script after the user has filled in the values.

Im wondering which would be best to start work on?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the specific details, but *most* of the time these sort of projects are best done completely in powershell. Consider the following:

```
$Creds = Get-Credential -Message 'Office 365 Login'
```

Users get a prompt to enter their credentials in an 'official' Windows dialog box, and you get the creds in powershell form automatically. Your form can be created entirely in powershell using the .NET framework, or even WPF I believe, whichever suits your fancy.

Comment: Agreed, I eventually just wrote a basic Powershell script for it. I wanted the GUI for some who couldn't execute a powershell script. http://blog.bondnet.co.uk/office-365-active-directory-new-user-scripting/